# Pointer issue when using with functions in c++

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

I have issues with my program.

When I launch the program, the console doesn't show the 2 numbers that it should , instead it only shows this:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.759 s
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


Test(int* Ptr)
{
    Ptr=(int*)malloc(8);

    if(Ptr==0)
    {
        printf("malloc error\n");
    }

    Ptr[0]=155;
    Ptr[1]=800;
}

int main()
{
    int* m_Ptr=0;

    Test(m_Ptr);

    printf("%d  %d",m_Ptr[0],m_Ptr[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the program? You pass `m_Ptr` by value to `Test` so the printing dereferences the original null ptr.

Comment: Try this instead: `Test(int*& Ptr)`

Comment: It doesn't even compile. You're missing `)` at the end of the 2nd `printf`, and missing `;` on the `return` statement. Is this what you actually compiled? And it's `program`, American spelling...

Comment: This looks like C, and not C++. Are you sure you know which language your program should be using?

Answer (score 0):

With `malloc(8)` you request **8 bytes**.
On a 64bit system `sizeof(int)` could be 8 bytes.
If so, the line `Ptr[1]=800;` actually writes to memory beyond the allocated Arena.

Try to change the malloc line to

`Ptr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2)`

Comment: That will not help with the fact that they dereference `NULL` in `printf` (which is definitely an error, compared to your hipotetical one).

Answer (score 0):

You're main issue is that the pointer you pass into test() is passed by copy. So `m_ptr` is null when its passed in and its still null when test returns.

You probably want to change your function slightly to something more like:

```cpp
int* Test()
{
    int * Ptr = (int*) malloc(20);

    if(Ptr==0)
    {
        printf("malloc error\n");
    }

    Ptr[0]=155;
    Ptr[1]=800;

    return Ptr; // Return the pointer by value
}
```

And use like (in main):

```cpp
int* m_Ptr = Test(m_Ptr);
// Now m_Ptr actually points to something...
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument `Ptr` in `test` is a different object in memory from `m_Ptr` in `main` - any changes to `test::Ptr` (such as assigning it the result of `malloc`) are not reflected in `main::m_Ptr`.  You will either have to pass a pointer or a reference to `m_Ptr` to `test`, or `test` will have to return a pointer value that you assign to `m_Ptr`:

```
m_Ptr = Test(); // returns pointer to newly allocated memory.
```

If this is meant to be C++, then ***don't*** use `malloc` (or `calloc`, or `realloc`).  Either use a standard container like a `vector` or `set` (which automatically grow as new items are added), or use the `new` operator to manually allocate memory to some kind of smart pointer.  ***Don't*** use C-style memory management in C++ code; it's labor-intensive, it's unsafe, and it's *easy* to get things wrong.